# How to specify the right directory for using HmmCleaner?

Tags: macos, perl, directory, bioinformatics, trim

I'm trying to use HmmCleaner to trim some sequences I've previously aligned and have been trying to follow the [home page's guidance](https://metacpan.org/dist/Bio-MUST-Apps-HmmCleaner/view/bin/HmmCleaner.pl).  I'm new to the Perl language and have only been using it to try and run HmmCleaner.

My current directory is:

`/Users/name/perl5/lib/perl5/Bio/MUST/Core`

And the line I'm trying to run in my terminal is

```
./HmmCleaner.pl '<Rep_MACSE_Default_ires1_NT.fasta>'
```

Where `Rep_MACSE_Default_ires1_NT.fasta` is the file I'm trying to trim.  I've also tried using `./Rep_MACSE_Default_ires1_NT.fasta` as my input file, but keep getting this error:

```
Can't open '<Rep_MACSE_Default_ires1_NT.fasta>' for reading: 'No such file or directory' at /Library/Perl/5.30/Bio/MUST/Core/Ali.pm line 394
```

Where do I need to put `HmmCleaner.pl` and my file so I can run the code without this error?  I think I've installed everything necessary for to use the program, but I suspect the files are just misplaced in regard to where the directory is reading from.

Comment: You probably don't want to include the `<>` around the filename.

Comment: It still throws the same error

Comment: Try with full path: `./HmmCleaner.pl /path/to/filename`   The source is using a particular system to read command-line arguments but `progname filename(s)` would _have to_ work

Comment: I'm now being throw this error `Can't call method "filename" on an undefined value at /Library/Perl/5.30/Bio/MUST/Drivers/Roles/Hmmerable.pm`

Comment: OK, got it going (so did the full path work?) -- now this error is about that `Hmmerable.pm` and we have no idea about it.  (Its method `filename` is apparently called with an undefined value, what it doesn't handle. Also, the error message should show you the line number in the module at which this happens?).  So you'd have to show us more code but this isn't looking good -- a library shouldn't throw an error like that for a basic invocation.  Is the file you run the program on good for it, of a kind (and detail) that is expected?